# Win10 - Auto-align TabTip.exe to default (bottom) position

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, microsoft-surface-pro

We use Win10 Surface Pro devices in a kiosk type manner. The user is in an enclosed shell with no access to Windows. However, the user does have admin privileges. The devices are managed by Intune.

Users have complained that the touch keyboard (TabTip.exe) can often be found on-screen in a position of the last user's choosing. The last user's preference is maintained through reboots.

We would like to (in order of preference):

1. Auto-align the keyboard to default position (centre, lower edge) at every boot
2. Disable ability for user to "float" the keyboard.

In an attempt to achieve (1) I tried setting the following keys to default values as shown, but it did not work.
`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7] "OptimizedKeyboardRelativeXPositionOnScreen"=dword:0000c350 "OptimizedKeyboardRelativeYPositionOnScreen"=dword:000186a0`

Thanks!